# combining dense (word embedding) and sparse vector (one hot encoding) but my kernel keeps crushing

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding, word-embedding

The function combine_sparse_and_dense_features(dense_vectors, sparse_features) is to combining dense vectors (word embedding) and sparse features (one hot encoding).

Dense vector array shape : (203621, 300)
Sparse features array shape (one hot encoding) : (203621, 70939)

Now I want to concatenate above two to a shape of (203621, 71239) but my kernel crashed.

```py
def combine_sparse_and_dense_features(dense_vectors, sparse_features):
    ar1= list(dense_vectors)
    ar1 = np.asarray(ar1)
    print(ar1.shape)
    ar2= sparse_features.toarray()
    print(ar2.shape)
    result = np.concatenate((ar1, ar2), axis=1)
    return result


dense_vectors = X_train['word_embedding']
sparse_features = X_train_ohe
combined_vectors = combine_sparse_and_dense_features(dense_vectors,
                                                     sparse_features)
```

Comment: `sparse_features.toarray()` is too large '

Comment: why do you want to combine two such different arrays?  What's the data like? words?  1/0?

Comment: thanks! it turned out the vector is too large because the one hot encoding of token was included..When removing those features, it works.